# change shortcode appearance in wordpress tinymce editor

Tags: wordpress, styles, tinymce, shortcode, appearance

Is it possible to change shortcode appearance in Wordpress TinyMCE editor? One of my clients has no HTML knowledge and it's really hard to explain him what not to edit on subpages.

By default, shortcodes look like this:

[image: Default view]

And I want to achieve this:

[image: Desired view]

Does TinyMCE support any kind of custom filtering?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you should use SyntaxHighlighter plugin with TinyMCE -  [Adding SyntaxHighlighter to TinyMCE](http://www.phoenixcode.net/post/2010/02/03/Adding-SyntaxHighlighter-plugin-to-tinyMCE.aspx)

After you integrate, create new brush that will color `[shortcode]`.

Comment: I'm wondering if it would work in visual editor, or in HTML view only?

Comment: I think that you can define that in your brush file.